# How do I get a refresh token for Google AdWords API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

My client is in another country. When I try to get the refresh token as described here https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/Using-OAuth-2.0, it asks me to log in. The client gave me the Google account credentials but Google then labels it as a suspicious login and wants a phone number and won't let me in!

[image: Imgur]

I even sent the client the URL obtained by running `GetRefreshToken.php`, and they visited the URL and sent me back the refresh token. When I tried to use the refresh token, it gave the error

```
An error has occurred: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

The refresh token *is* working for the test MCC account that I created myself using a throwaway GMail account. I think it would be silly to have the client set up a development environment and run the code themselves to get the refresh token.

Comment: your client should not be giving you there Google credentials this completely defeats the purpose of Open Authentication.    What is happening to you should be happening.  You as a developer should not be trying to authenticate someone elses account.   What exactly does your application do?

Comment: @DaImTo I cannot log in as myself because I already have an AdWords account. Google only lets you use one AdWords account per email.